# Selenium: element not interactable, Google Maps automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just created a Selenium code to get the travel time between 2 set of coordinates in Google Maps. "output.txt" is a list of coordinates such as "19.5860438,-99.2715737 to 19.6028627,-99.185743". When I run the code it appears "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable", but if I change this part of code

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys(y)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)**
```

by changing the "y" with the actual coordinate the code works perfectly, but if it tries to loop in the list the error appears.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

File = "output.txt"

a_file = open(File)

lines = a_file.readlines()

for x in range(2):
    for y in lines:
        Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")

        search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search.send_keys(y)
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            transporte = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".vxq1Hc:nth-child(3) .Wnt0je-urwkYd-WAutxc-icon"))
            )
        except:
            driver.quit()

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", transporte)

        time.sleep(3)

        directions = driver.find_element_by_class_name("xB1mrd-T3iPGc-iSfDt-n5AaSd")


        with open('tiempo.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(directions.text)


        driver.quit()
```

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Output.txt is the following list

```
19.5860438,-99.2715737 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.6569881,-99.0622077 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.6131191,-98.9537177 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4916535,-99.2277299 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.5304865,-99.2809449 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.5424037,-99.0557252 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4941883,-98.9365922 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4076984,-99.1923676 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4514075,-99.2727052 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4504363,-99.0018235 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.4060793,-99.0722047 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.3700488,-99.2070883 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.3284059,-99.1695301 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.3381165,-99.040433 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.3747191,-99.0926181 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.3023707,-99.1955472 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.1873019,-99.1646482 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.2369048,-99.0544416 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
19.2842243,-99.0118695 to 19.6028627,-99.185743
```

Comment: `readlines()` gives lines with `'\n'` at the end and you may need to remove it `y = y.strip()`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could create `driver` only once - before `for`-loops. It could run faster and not ask again for cookies (at least it asks all time on my computer)

Comment: maybe you should use another `WebDriverWait` to wait for element.

Comment: Perhaps you need to move `transporte = WebDriverWait(...` out of the try..except block because you don't receive the actual error this way